# Что не так с этим кодом

Tags: c++, clang++

Решил сделать программу которая ищет TODO: в файлах
Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

ifstream inFile;

const int SIZE = 60;
int  i,d;

string todo[200];

int main()
{
    char filename[SIZE];
    string filecontents;
    cout <<"Place this executable to source folder" << endl
         <<"and enter filename to start search" << endl
         <<"filename can't start from space" << endl
         <<"Maximum count of TODOs is 200."<< endl
         <<"Maximum size is 60 symbols. Enter q to quit." << endl;
    while (cin.getline(filename, SIZE))
    {
        if (filename[0] == 'q')
        {
            cout << "Terminating...\n";
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
        else if (filename[0] != ' ')
        {
            if (filename[0] != '\n')
            {
                inFile.open(filename);
                if (!inFile.is_open())
                {
                    cout << "Can't open file called " << filename << endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    int count = 1;
                    string temp;
                    cout << "Opened file called " << filename << endl <<
                         "Searching for todos..." << endl;
                    while (getline(inFile, temp))
                    {
                        filecontents += temp + '\n';
                    }
                    while (i < filecontents.size())
                    {
                        if (filecontents[i] == 'T')
                        {
                            if (filecontents[i+1] == 'O')
                            {
                                if (filecontents[i+2] == 'D')
                                {
                                    if (filecontents[i+3] == 'O')
                                    {
                                        if (filecontents[i+4] == ':')
                                        {
                                            string temp = "";
                                            char temp2;
                                            int temp3 = i + 5;
                                            while (temp2 != '\n')
                                            {
                                                temp += filecontents[temp3]; //TODO: test todo m8
                                                temp2 = filecontents[temp3+1];
                                                ++temp3;
                                            }
                                            ++d;
                                            todo[d] = temp;
                                            temp = "";
                                            cout << "Found todo: " << todo[d] << endl;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                }

            }
            else
                cout << "Please enter correct filename according to rules:\n"; // TODO: another todo as always
        }
        else
            cout << "Please enter correct filename according to rules:\n";
        inFile.close();
        d = 0;

        cout<< "Please enter filename: ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Когда запускаю эту скомпилированную программу на собственном исходном коде, он читает только первый TODO и только один раз. Как это можно исправить? Или я просто слепой и не вижу очевидного?
Компилятор: Clang++ LLVM Compiler
Система: Fedora 23

Comment: Вот казалось бы - простейший случай. Программа ищет TODO в текстовых файлах. Но хочу обратить внимание, что на такой "простой" проблеме можно споткнуться несколько раз. Начиная с того, что исходная кодировка файло может быть разной. Да-да-да, я видел Unicode-закодированные файлы *.c и *.cpp. Более того - простой и тупой код может споткнуться еще и на русскоязычных CP1251 текстах. Кодировка символа 'я' соответствует символу 0xFF, который, как некоторые думают, отмечает конец файла (EOF)... и т.д. Может вообще с++ не лучший язык для работы с текстовыми строками и лучше попробовать что-то другое?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С этим кодом всё не так. Начиная с глобальных переменных. С того, что он ищет неправильные TODO (во-первых, двоеточие не нужно, во-вторых, найдёт и SOMETODO: в комментариях, и TODO: как метку, и переменную, заканчивающуюся на TODO в тернарном операторе, и т.д.) С непонятного ограничения на количество найденых строк. И заканчивая лапшой.

Но даже с учётом поиска только подстрок без учёта контекста всё это можно написать покрасивше, попонятней и попригодней для отладки:

```
const char TODO[] = "TODO:";

static size_t substring_count(const char * where, const char * what,
        size_t what_length) {
    size_t count = 0;
    const char * ptr = strstr(where, what);
    while (ptr) {
        count++;
        ptr = strstr(ptr + what_length, what);
    }
    return count;
}

int main() {
    size_t todos = 0;
    std::vector<std::string> lines;
    std::ifstream inFile;
    std::string temp;

    inFile.open("123.txt");
    while (std::getline(inFile, temp)) {
        size_t todo_count = substring_count(temp.c_str(), TODO,
                sizeof(TODO) - 1);
        if (todo_count) {
            todos += todo_count;
            lines.push_back(temp);
        }
    }
    inFile.close();
    std::cout << "Found " << todos << " TODO in " << lines.size() << " lines."
            << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Воу, про векторя я забыл когда это писал, про size_t вообще не слыхал, да и про strstr() тоже. Что называется делал на основе своих знаний :D . Что-ж, надо пойти про векторы хоть почитать... А так спасибо...